# Product analogue of Egyptian fractions

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, products, egyptian-fractions

**Background**

An *Egyptian fraction* is a finite sum of distinct unit fractions, in which each denominator is not bigger than the next one. In other words, it is a representation of $a/b$ such that $$\frac{a}{b} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{c_{n}} $$ with $c_{1} \leq c_{2} \leq c_{3} \leq \dots c_{N} .$ For instance, we have $$ \frac{80}{99} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{18} + \frac{1}{396} .$$

I'm currently exploring the idea of an *Egyptian product* (*). It is a representation of a fraction $a/b$ with $b>a$ such that $$\frac{a}{b} = \prod_{k=1}^{K} \left(1-\frac{1}{a_{k}} \right) ,$$ where $a_{1} \leq a_{2} \leq a_{3} \leq \dots \leq a_{K} .$ If we take the previous fraction again as an example, we find: $$ \frac{80}{99} = \left(1-\frac{1}{9} \right) \left( 1-\frac{1}{11} \right). $$

**Questions**

1. Has this notion of an Egyptian product been described in the mathematical literature before?
2. Does every fraction $0 < \frac{a}{b} < 1 $ have an Egyptian product representation?
3. Is the Egyptian product a new and "interesting" representation in the sense that they can't be reduced to finding Egyptian fraction sums (or perhaps a particular type thereof) somehow?

**Notes**

(*) Sometimes, a particular type of Egyptian fraction - the *Engel expansion* - is also called an Egyptian product. The concept of an Egyptian product I have in mind is different.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to question 2 is yes: for any positive integers $m$ and $n$,
$$\frac m{m+n}=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{m+k}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you! Any idea about the other two questions?

Comment: @MaxMuller : My guess for the answer to questions 1 and 3 is no, because there are infinitely many (not very interesting) EPRs for every rational in the unit interval. For example, $$\frac m{m+n}=\prod_{j=1}^{kn}\left(1-\frac1{km+j}\right)\quad(m,n,k\in \Bbb Z_+).$$

Comment: Hm, alright. I did find distinct and short EPRs for the same fraction: $5/16 = (1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/16) = (1-1/2)(1-1/4)(1-1/6)  $. These are considerably shorter than the ones generated by the products given in your answer - perhaps restricting the products to a certain length can make the concept more interesting.

Comment: @MaxMuller : Yes. There would be only finitely many EPRs of minimal length (MEPRs). I don't have an opinion on whether mathematically interesting questions about MEPRs can be posed and answered. One observation I would make is that MEPRs of numbers close to $0$ would generally be much longer than those of numbers close to $1$.